# How can I get the previous month if the month is kind of number, not a format of time

Tags: sql, oracle

Now, my case is I have two kinds of variable:

1. LOG_DTM
2. LOG_DTM_ID

- For the 1): It is store the data about month.
- For the 2): It is the data about turning LOG_DTM into number, so it is not an expression of time, just a number.

For example, if the LOG_DTM = OCT 6 2022, then LOG_DTM_ID = 20221006.

The Question is I want to find the last month data from database,
For the LOG_DTM, I am doing in this way(it is working):

```
select * 
from table 
where
    LOG_DTM between TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM') 
    and LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1))
```

However, for the LOG_DTM_ID, it cannot work:

```
select * 
from table 
where
    LOG_DTM_ID between to_number(to_charc(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM')))
                   and to_number(to_charc(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1))))
```

May I know whats wrong with me? Is my logic flow wrong or syntax wrong? Thanks very much.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for the sample data that replicates the problem; the full details of the issue/error with your query; and the expected output for your sample data.

Comment: `TO_CHARC` should be `TO_CHAR`.

Comment: one more thing to add ,  is LOG_DTM_ID should be the number of "yyyymmddhh", again it is number.

Comment: The ERROR is :
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: It doesn't work even it is changes to  to_char

Comment: Your `to_char()` isn't specifying the format model - which you mentioned in a previous comment. Also, if your `log_dtm` values have non-midnight times (and `_dtm` suggests to me it's supposed to represent a date/time, not just a date) then using `between` will miss out most of the data from the last day of the month.

Comment: but how can I to_char() a last month of current month?

Comment: If the id is a just a numerical value then you might just apply *integer* division: `(log_dtm_id / 100) * 100` would give 20221000 and you could simply look up with >

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't store date information redundantly. The string can always be re-constructed any time from the number, so I'd leave that to the application. If that is localised (German, Spanish, ...) it wouldn't be able to use the string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `TO_CHAR` and not `TO_CHARC`; and
2. Include a format model as the second argument to `TO_CHAR`.
3. You can simplify the upper bound to `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm')-INTERVAL '1' SECOND`

```sql
Select * 
from   table_name
Where  LOG_DTM_ID between to_number(to_char(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24'))
                  AND     to_number(to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm')-INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 'YYYYMMDDHH24'))
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  LOG_DTM    DATE,
  LOG_DTM_ID NUMBER(10,0)
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(log_dtm, 'YYYYMMDDHH24')))
);

INSERT INTO table_name (log_dtm)
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LOG_DTM | LOG_DTM_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-06 10:15:39 | 2022090610 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5u6wCJis)

Comment: @benjjm Use the query in the answer rather than trying to get it to work using the `LAST_DAY` function.

Comment: It works, Thanks!!! @MT0 for your help, the format make my mind break.!!

Comment: Actually, If I want to modifiy by using  LAST_DAY function, is it correct?


LOG_DTM_ID between to_number(to_char(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM'), 'YYYYMMDDHH'))
AND  to_number(to_char(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1),'YYYYMMDDHH'))

It seems not working

Comment: @benjjm No, you do not have enough closing brackets and you miss out the times from 01:00:00 until 23:59:59 on the last day. Just use `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND`, its much simpler.

Comment: So, it means that your version:
LOG_DTM_ID between to_number(to_char(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24')) AND
to_number(to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm')-INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 'YYYYMMDDHH24'))

is inclued the 00:00am of first day to 23:59 pm of last day right?

Comment: If you really want it then: `LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1)) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND` but you are using two extra function calls compared to `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND` and it becomes much harder to understand with all that extra complexity.

Comment: @benjjm Why don't you test it? [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HUHApB8Q)